# Hamcrest matcher for Object... parameters

Tags: java, jmock, hamcrest

I got method of class

```
interface Class1{
    void method1(SomeObject... parameters);
}
```

I have a custom Hamcrest matcher

```
public class SomeObjectMatcher extends BaseMatcher<SomeObject>{...}
```

How to write expectation matching that object passed to the method1

```
SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject(...);
...

mockery.checking(new Expectations(){{
    oneOf(class1).method1(with(new SomeObjectMatcher(someObject1)));
}}
```

The actual call is

```
class1.method1(someObject);
```

The passed object and the expected one are same, but SomeObjectMatcher fails, because the actual passed parameter is not someObject1, but it is SomeObject[]{someObject1} (array with only one object - someObject1)?
Is there a way to add a new matcher in the chain, something like

```
oneOf(class1).method1(with(arrayHas(new SomeObjectMatcher(someObject1))));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `arrayHas` with `hasItemInArray`. To match multiple items in an array you can use `arrayContaining` and `arrayContainingInAnyOrder`.